# Is a digital wallet created by blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, data-security

Currently reading an article [here](https://www.pcmag.com/article/351486/blockchain-the-invisible-technology-thats-changing-the-wor), I came across the following sentence which really confused me:

> Through the digital "wallet" a blockchain creates around not only
>   virtual money but the pieces of data that make up your identity,
>   blockchain will act as a gatekeeper of sorts to how we interact with
>   the digital world

Does the author really mean: a blockchain creates a digital wallet around 1)virtual money and 2)certain pieces of data, and through this wallet the blockchain acts as a gatekeeper to...? How come a digital wallet is created by blockchain?

Comment: That sentence sounds like pure nonsense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer of that sentence did a poor job explaining things.

A blockchain (the data structure) does not create a wallet.  It is the data that a wallet uses to determine the state of the money it manages.  It is also the data that new transactions are appended to, thus changing that state, and wallets submit those transactions.

A blockchain does not create a wallet, but wallets do help to create a blockchain.

Comment: Do you mean a blockchain creates the data you mentioned?

Comment: A blockchain *is* the data I mentioned.